# In Corda, what does `getPaper()` mean in the tutorial “Writing a contract test”?

Tags: corda

I am following the following Corda tutorial: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-test-dsl.html.

Can someone explain the line `val inState = getPaper()`? It doesn’t appear before this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a test method to return a new commercial paper state.

Currently, beyond the Hello, World! tutorials (https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-introduction.html and https://docs.corda.net/tut-two-party-introduction.html), the tutorials are not supposed to follow on from each other to create a full CorDapp. They are simply examples of how various features work.

It may also be helpful to look at the various sample CorDapps defined here: https://www.corda.net/samples/.

Answer (score 1):

I found

```
    override fun getPaper(): ICommercialPaperState = JavaCommercialPaper.State(
            megaCorp.ref(123),
            megaCorp.party,
            1000.DOLLARS `issued by` megaCorp.ref(123),
            TEST_TX_TIME + 7.days
    )
```

useful (from [CommercialPaperTests.kt](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/master/finance/contracts/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/finance/contracts/CommercialPaperTests.kt))

I translate this to:

```
    private OwnableState getPaper() {
        PartyAndReference partyAndReference = new PartyAndReference((AbstractParty) this.megaCorp.getParty(), OpaqueBytes.of((byte) 0));
        Amount<Issued<Currency>> issuedAmount = Amount.fromDecimal(new BigDecimal(1000), new Issued<Currency> (partyAndReference, Currency.getInstance(Locale.US)));
        return (OwnableState) new CommercialPaper.State(this.megaCorp.ref((byte) 123), this.megaCorp.getParty(), issuedAmount, Instant.now().plus(7, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing this would be as below

```
private companion object {
    val testIssuance = bigCorp.ref(111)
    val testPounds: Cash.State = 1999.POUNDS.CASH issuedBy testIssuance

}

fun getPaper(): CommercialPaperState {
    return CommercialPaperState(testIssuance, testIssuance.party, testPounds.amount , Instant.now()+10.days)
    }
```

Or the below is another more complicated way of doing it without using the Cash provided as part of Finance CorDapp shipped along with Corda 4

```
import net.corda.finance.`issued by`

private companion object {
     val bigCorp = TestIdentity((CordaX500Name("BigCorp", "New York", "GB")))
     val testIssuance = bigCorp.ref((("JoinKey").toByte()))
     val testAmount = Amount<Currency>(1000,Currency.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY))

}

fun getPaper(): CommercialPaperState {
    return CommercialPaperState(testIssuance, testIssuance.party, testAmount `issued by` testIssuance, Instant.now()+10.days)
}
```